# Collections not showing on page

Tags: meteor

I have published a `countries` collection which I want to show in a table in the `countriesList` template. So I have added this to the router:

```
Router.route('/countries_list', {
  name: 'countriesList',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('countries');
  },
  data: function() {
    return Countries.find();
  }
});
```

And this is how the template looks like:

```
  {{#each countries}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
```

But the page stays empty. However, the collection is filled on the client, if I check the browser console and do `Countries.findOne();`, I get this result:

```
Object {_id: "WWJhMBne4CiEdbbdg", name: "England"}
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably your route doesn't wait for subscription, got the same problem couple topics lower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You template is making the assumption that the cursor is being stored in `coutries`. It isn't. It would be if your `data` hook looked like:

```js
return {countries: Countries.find()};
```

As your code is written, the cursor *is* the context for your template so this should work:

```html
{{#each this}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```